# how can i get parase data from another website using php

Tags: php, json

I want to get decode data from server to server
server sender sends echo text like title decode to the receiver server
I use `json_decode($json ,tue);` and     `$json = file_get_contents($url ,true);` not working

it is show the title in the sender server but does not get in the receiver server

parse domain sender includes this code

```php
<?php
$json = '{
    "title": "PHP"

}';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->title;
?>
```

the second domain receiver from the domain sender

```php
<?php

$url = 'https://domain sender';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$jo = json_decode($json);
echo $jo->title;


if ($jo = 'PHP') {

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET web_status = 'web_int' WHERE website = '".$url."' ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
    }
    echo"good";
}else{
    if ($json !== 'PHP') {

        $sql = "UPDATE users SET web_status = 'pendding' WHERE website = '".$url."' ";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        }
        echo"bad";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Firstly, you change the `$jo` variable value instead of comparing it with 'PHP' string

Comment: `$jo = 'PHP'` ... should be `==` instead of `=`. Do you need us to explain the difference, or is it just a typo?

Comment: i try it not work

Comment: i mean not get title in the receiver domain

Comment: You realise that the remote site simply outputs the title as text? So there is no JSON for the receiver to decode. It's just plain text. `$data = file_get_contents($url); if ($data == "PHP") {` should be enough for the start of the script.

Comment: @VORTAPLUS `i mean not get title in the receiver domain` well yes, obviously. But have you tried to investigate it more closely? As in, checking what you _do_ receive, what your code variables actually contain, and what path the code takes? Have you got PHP error reporting enabled? If something doesn't do what you expect, you have to go through the code line by line to try and find out why it happened and where it started to go wrong. Otherwise you can never solve any problems in your code. This is a basic skill you should have been learning since the first day you wrote a computer program.

Comment: https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP. I suggest that you study it.

Comment: i canot see any change in this code $data = file_get_contents($url); if ($data == "PHP") {

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that, sorry. Try to be specific instead of vague. And **please do some basic debugging**. For example: `$data = file_get_contents($url); var_dump($data);`. What do you see? Remember we cannnot run your code for you, so it's your job to test it in detail.

Comment: I am talking about getting data from the echo from another URL, not from the current url using JSON in PHP

Comment: We can only work with what you show us in the question. According to what you posted, your sender should output simply the word "PHP", without any JSON. If you want to talk about some other data, then show us an example of that instead. We are not mind-readers.

Comment: I run the test code already you use encode not decode from var_dump I don't want to get all website data I just need echo text

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say. I'm asking you simply to _test_ what you are _actually receiving_ from the sender, because the code to decode what you _think_ you're receiving is not working. This var_dump is part of the debugging process. You need to study how to debug because clearly you do not understand this basic skill. Once we can see what is really downloaded from the sender, then we can understand how to process it correctly.

Comment: But I can tell you now, based on the sender code you provided, that the only thing that file_get_contents will download from the sender will be the word "PHP" - this is a demo of your sender code: https://3v4l.org/128nE. I only ask you to use the var_dump just to prove it to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your sender code will output only the title value, which is "PHP".

Therefore, there is no need for the receiver to try and decode any JSON, because the data it downloads is simply one word, in plain text format.

There are also a couple of other simplifications and improvements we can make to the receiver code, so that we end up with this:

```
$url = 'https://domain sender';
$data = file_get_contents($url); //downloaded data is plain text, not JSON
$status = "";

// a simple switch is usually neater than a lot of "if"s
switch ($data) {
  case "PHP":
    $status = "web_int";
    echo "good";
    break;
  default:
    $status = "pending";
    echo "bad";
    break;
}

//always use prepared statements and parameters to execute queries reliably and safely!
$sql = "UPDATE users SET web_status = ? WHERE website = ? ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($status, $url));
```

Comment: the value returned empty I mean     echo "bad";
 and not update the value in the database too

Comment: That must mean that your remote URL returned something different than "PHP". If it returns PHP, then the code works: https://3v4l.org/T8AqU . Again...have you debugged it? Add `var_dump($data);` after the file_get_contents line and tell me what it outputs.

Comment: Also turn on error reporting in PHP and for your database library to see if you get any errors about the database update. One more time: you cannot solve any problems in your code just by guessing. You have to _investigate_.

Comment: I am tried all your suggestions but all failed am not guessing I make all you said I need to solve my problem

Comment: I use this JSON code {
 "title": "PHP"
} but not get it to another server IT IS shown in the same server only but does not get any data to the receiver server

Comment: Again. **be specific**. `i use this json code`...where? And how does it relate to PHP? `another server`...what other server? The question is about the code you've shown in your post, not about some other server or other code. Are you saying you changed something compared to what is in your question?

Comment: sender domain means >>> server one  &&&& receiver domain means server two

Comment: Anyway if you don't get any data from the sender, perhaps there is some other issue outside the code itself. Check the sender server by making a request directly from your browser. Do you see the data then? Maybe your PHP receiver has a networking issue preventing it from accessing the sender? We don't know anything about the context in which you are running this code. is

Comment: `sender domain means >>> server one &&&& receiver domain means server two`...yeah I know that. But that doesn't clarify anything I asked about.

Comment: on (server one or domain one) I have the first code and I need (server two or domain two) to receive data or echo values from (server one or domain one )  USING PHP

Comment: Yes. I know that. It sounds all the same as what you have shown. So, please do what I suggested. 1) Check independently that the sender is working by loading the sender URL in your browser. 2) Add var_dump($data); after the file_get_contents line in your receiver code and tell me exactly what it outputs. 3) Check whether there is any firewall rule or similar issue preventing your receiver code from accessing the sender URL.

Comment: 'var_dump' gives all contents and this is what i am use in '$json = file_get_contents($url ,true);
echo var_dump($json);'

Comment: `gives all contents`....how many times do I have to say it? Tell me **exactly** what it says. BE SPECIFIC. STOP BEING VAGUE. Computer programming is all about precise information.

Comment: `echo var_dump($json);`...no, I said to use `var_dump($json);`. Don't invent code I didn't tell you to use! And if you bother to [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or learn how to debug as I told you earlier, you'll know that var_dump already outputs automatically without needing to echo it. Seriously, you need to pay more attention to _details_.

Comment: gives all contents... I mean it shows the domain one home page in domain two

Comment: Ok so you're trying to access a totally different page than shown in your question? Your receiver code is **only** designed to detect the word "PHP" in the output. If the output contains **anything else** then it will echo "bad". That's how it's designed. That's the code **you** wrote.  So I don't know why you are expecting it to understand some other output? What are you actually trying to achieve with this code? What is the _real_ requirement you are trying to implement?

Comment: i replace echo var_dump($json); to var_dump($json); not make diffrent  it display the domain one home page in domain two

Comment: Yeah that's fine, the point was you need to do exactly what people tell you when they give you a code sample, not add extra bits at random :-)

Comment: Note: I've given you a solution to work with the specific output given in your sender code above. It is not designed to work with anything else. I've correctly answered your question. If you actually wanted something else, that's not my fault :-)

Comment: I am trying to put a code on another site and check if this code has been deleted or not even I want to check it through the value I added, which is PHP. This means that when I re-download the link to my site, it determines whether the other site puts this code or this word on the page or not

Comment: anyway thanks for your help I think you can not  Exactly what do I mean?

Comment: So you want to search for the word PHP somewhere _within_ some bigger output? That's not what you asked about originally

Comment: that is what I am asking do you have a solution

Answer (score 1):

On sending server you have `echo $data->title;` which echo/sends 'PHP'

Then you have `$jo = json_decode($json); echo $jo->title;` on receiving server. But the `->title` isn't needed because you don't send an array. The variable `$jo` already has the value 'PHP'.

**Update:**

Change

```php
$url = 'https://domain sender';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$jo = json_decode($json);
echo $jo->title;
```

To

```php
$url = 'https://domain sender';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Tested it and it works.

Comment: how can I send an array may be it will work with me ?!

Comment: Replace `echo $jo->title;` with `echo $jo; var_dump($jo);` What u get as response?

Comment: echo $jo->title; with echo $jo; var_dump($jo); gives me NULL

Comment: @VORTAPLUS I have edited my solution and tested it for you. 

Comment: I show all contents of the server one does not get title value

Comment: Have updated again, we gonna try with curl this time.

Comment: same it is display all page contents for another domain But it does not give a specific value PHP

Comment: LoL, so the complete other website is imported?  You can't have a websitepage with this. You need to make a separate file, with nothing in it. Only the first code you posted.
`<?php
$json = '{
    "title": "PHP"

}';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->title;
?>`

Comment: hhhh , all i need to get specific value 'PHP'

Comment: Therefor Make new file: specificvalue.php with ONLY this code `<?php $json = '{     "title": "PHP"  }'; $data = json_decode($json); echo $data->title; ?>` Then on 2nd website the CURL code above with `$url = 'https://example.com/specificvalue.php';`